# Prove $P(A \cap B) = P(A) -P(A \cap B^c)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B^c)$, where $B^c$ is the *complement* of $B$.

How would I start? Should I implement the multiplication rule here?

Comment: What do you want to prove, the result in the title of your question or the one in the first line of the text of the question.  (Hint: the one in the title is true, the one in the text is false)

Comment: Title; both are consistent now sorry

Comment: So, use the third axiom of probability on $A$ after partitioning it into the disjoint union of two events $(A\cap B)$ and $(A\cap B^c)$ as Michael Albanese hinted to you.

Comment: I'd suggest that you draw a Venn Diagram-type picture to gain an intuition for the problem.  This is one of those cases where the proof flows pretty quickly from the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For any $A, B \subseteq X$, $X = B \cup B^c$ and $A = A\cap X$.